# Find DEMs based on specific geographical features

Tags: dem, search

Is it possible to find DEMs based on certain specific natural features?

For instance, is there a way to look for regions of the world or of specific countries that have mountains that have an altitude of, say, 2000m or 3000m?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Maybe you should start with global low resolution DEM, identify those features using calc, and then refine your search in those areas with higher resolution data?

Comment: Have a look at [OpenDEM](https://www.opendem.info/index.html)?

Comment: "Is there a way" includes "collect the information needed and calculate it yourself" so the answer is clearly "Yes." It takes more effort that way, though. This is a generic problem with "Is it possible" questions, which can be addressed by focusing on "How is it possible" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way might be to look for the specific geographical features first ... and then look for the corresponding regions' DEMs.

So, for mountains, there's this handy Wikipedia page that lists mountains by elevation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountains_by_elevation

Find the peak before finding the corresponding DEM.